# User object to every controller if authenticated

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-5.1, middleware

The 'problem' I'm facing now is that with every controller that is used when the user is authenticated I have to request `$user = Auth::user();`. An example:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $building = Building::findOrFail($request->building);
    $user->buildings()->save($building);

    return response(['status' => 'OK']);
}
```

As you can imagine I need to request the user object many more times, even in this one controller. How can I improve this? I have thought about declaring a user variable in the Controller parent class, or using Middleware. I read about dependency injection but I don't fully understand it and I can't figure out how to implement it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a parent controller say BaseController and extend every controller from this controller.

```
class BaseController extends Controller{
    protected $user;

    function __construct(){
        $this->$user = Auth::user();
    }
}
```

Now say in your pagesController

```
class PagesController extends BaseController{
    function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $building = Building::findOrFail($request->building);
        $this->user->buildings()->save($building);

        return response(['status' => 'OK']);
    }

}
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot. I don't know if it's conventionally the 'right' way to solve the issue but it's very clear to me what is happening so I think I will use this. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: I implemented this and it works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: glad it workes. you should accept this if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set authentication in route

```
Route::get('profile', [
     'middleware' => 'auth',
     'uses' => 'ProfileController@show'
]);
```

or in construcor of controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

And then inside of controller you can get instance of the authenticated user by

```
$request->user()
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was already wondering how to implement it this way, this is very useful!